# how to list all users who tweeted a given keyword using twitter api and tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

How to list name of users who tweeted with given keyword along with count of tweets from them ?
I am using python and tweepy.

I used tweepy to list JSON result in a file  by filter(track["keyword"])
but doesn't know how to list users who tweeted given keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your data has been loaded into `JSON` format, you can access the username by calling `tweet['user']['screen_name']`. Where `tweet` is whatever varibale you have assigned that holds the `JSON` object for that specific tweet.

Comment: How to do this "after starting, every 1 minute program should print user names based on the tweets of last 5 minutes"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can just append the data you get from `tweet['user']['screen_name']` into a list using [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html)